# Bootstrap Dropdown get value of selected item

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

With the Bootstrap dropdown-toggle buttons is there any way to show the value that has just been selected?

```
<form action="/output/" name="InputCacheCheck" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
    <div class="input-prepend input-append">
        <div class="btn-group">

            <button class="btn dropdown-toggle" name="recordinput" data-toggle="dropdown">
            Record
            <span class="caret"></span>
            </button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li><a href="#">A</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">CNAME</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">MX</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">PTR</a></li>
            </ul>
        <input class=".input-large" name="hostnameinput" id="appendedInputButton" type="text">
        <button class="btn" type="submit">Lookup</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Also the name recordinput isn't being supplied within the forms POST data.
Any ideas?

Comment: You're going to have to do this yourself with a bit of JS - create a hidden input and set a value to it when a dropdown item is selected

Comment: Which is how we did it in 1999 with Visual Interdev. Thanks Bootstrap!

Answer (score 10):

You should be able to change the dropdown text like this..

```
$(".dropdown-menu li a").click(function(){
  var selText = $(this).text();
  $(this).parents('.btn-group').find('.dropdown-toggle').html(selText+' <span class="caret"></span>');
});
```

**Demo http://www.bootply.com/64302**

How is the form being 'POST'ed?

Comment: Thanks, the forms action is to post the form back ot a given url. 
Also is there anyway to keep the length of the drop down box the same ?

Answer (score 0):

Or you can do it likes this...

Using (documemt).on seems to work more consistently than targeting the click event from the element class. Also, by giving the button element an ID helps with assigning your dropdown selection in this case.

```
   $(document).on('click', '.dropdown-menu li a', function () {
            var selText = $(this).text();
            $('#dLabel').html(selText + '<span class="caret"</span>');
        });



   <div class="dropdown">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" id="dLabel" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" data-target="#">
            Lists
            <span class="caret"></span>
        </button>
        <ul id="drpdn_List" runat="server" class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownmenu">
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case you should not use Bootstrap dropdown toggle. This is useful to show one or more hyperlinks when user click / hover on a button.

if you want style dropdown, you can use some other plugins like [selectfx](https://www.npmjs.com/package/periodicjs.component.selectfx) which acts/returns value like a dropdown.