# How to display selected item with icons in Bootstrap dropdown title?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I want to ask some help. I am new to Bootstrap and JS. I tried find solution by myself, but do not have enough knowledge for solution yet. I have problem in dropdown class. I using JS  [from this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17127572/bootstrap-dropdown-get-value-of-selected-item) to make drop down menu items selected, everything works fine, but when i use item links with icon class, they dont be displayed on heading, and after page reload, heading title come to default (.dropdown a class text) . [you can see it here](http://www.bootply.com/99235#).http://www.bootply.com/99235#

Here is HTML

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default container" role="navigation">
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Menu<b class="caret"></b></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i>Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i>Search</a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-gift"></i>Gift</a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-music"></i>Twitter</a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></i>Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Here is JS

```
 $(".dropdown-menu li a").click(function(){
  var selText = $(this).text();
  $(this).parents('.dropdown').find('.dropdown-toggle').html(selText+'<span class="caret"></span>');
});
```

JS asking select only text not icon class, so what changes i must make to solve these two problems?

Sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 3):

```
$(".dropdown-menu li a").click(function(){
  var selText = $(this).html();
  $(this).parents('.dropdown').find('.dropdown-toggle')
         .html(selText+'<span class="caret"></span>');
});
```

does the job (see [this fork of your bootply](http://www.bootply.com/99259)).

Comment: sorry, i don't understand what you mean.

Comment: Big thanks!!! its work great, thanks. But what about page refreshing, when reload page, dropdown title comes to default, can fix it somehow?